# How can I fix my MKOverlayRenderer now that I'm using Swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, swift2, xcode7, mkoverlay

So when I was using Swift 1.2, this function worked fine and gave me the functionality I needed.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {

    if overlay is MKPolyline {
        let pr = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        pr.strokeColor = self.lightBlue
        pr.lineWidth = 14
        return pr
    }
//I get the error here, because I need to return something    
}
```

Now, I get an error saying "Missing return in a function expected to return 'MKOverlayRenderer'".

Is this still how this method is used? What can I do to remedy this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer
```

will only be called for each overlay that you add to your instance of MKMapView.

If you only add an `MKPolyline` to your mapView, you can be sure that when this delegate function is called, the `overlay` parameter will be of type `MKPolyline`. Since this is the case, there is no reason to check if the overlay parameter is an instance of `MKPolyline` with `if overlay is MKPolyline`. You can just do this:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    let pr = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    pr.strokeColor = self.lightBlue
    pr.lineWidth = 14
    return pr
}
```

If you ever add a different type of overlay to your MKMapView, you can do this:

```
if overlay is MKPolyline {
    // return renderer for MKPolyline overlay
    return mkPolylineRenderer
} else {
    // handle the different type of overlay...
    return otherTypeOfOverlayRenderer
}
```

The Swift compiler is intelligent enough to infer from the if/else block that something will always be returned.

Comment: This worked and was very detailed, thank you so much.